# Where should I placed my business logic?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using Repository Pattern, Service pattern, unit of work pattern. I am little bit confused that where should I place my business logic. whether It should be in the service or in the repository class.

Comment: Repository is to abstract the data layer, service is where you put your core logic.

Comment: Generally business logic would belong in the business models.  The repositories are just for fetching/persisting those models to a data store.  Services can have some procedural logic that applies to the service itself, but be careful not to make the whole thing too procedural.

Comment: In a seperate layer. A typical architecture would be a Data Access Layer, above it a Bussiness Logic Layer, and above it a Service Layer. But the question is off topic for the site. Try here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1):

Usually business logic is added to services and repository is used to access the data.